# Roxygen documentation for existing generics

Tags: r, roxygen2

I wrote a `show()` method for the S4 class `myclass` which I had defined in my package. I generated documentation for class and method with roxygen2. Everything works nicely, except that I get the following warning in R CMD check results:

> checking for missing documentation entries ...   WARNING
>   Undocumented S4 methods: 
>   generic 'length' and siglist 'myclass'

How do I go about documenting `show` generic which I did not write myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, using explicit `@aliases` and `@docType` tags solved the issue for me. My documentation block now looks like this:

```
#' Show method for objects of class \code{myclass}.
#'
#' @docType methods
#' @name show-myclass
#' @rdname show-myclass
#' @aliases show-myclass show,myclass-method
#'
#' @param x A \code{myclass} object.
#'
#' @export
```